# Class not found when running test class in INtelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-14

I am experimenting on writing test automation for mobile app, and after going through numerous incompatibility issues, I thought I have sorted it out. However, this is not the case as I encounter this seemingly innocent yet devastating issue.

test class code

```
package com.example.test;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
//@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)

public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    private AndroidDriver driver;
    @Before
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5444");
        capabilities.setCapability("platFormName","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.mol.molwallet.uat");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.mol.molwallet.start.SplashActivity");
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset","true");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"),capabilities);
    }
    @Test
    public void myFirstTest() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='LOG IN']")).click();
        //assertEquals("com.example.test", appContext.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29+'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    //implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
    //implementation("com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1")
   //implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')

}
if(hasProperty('buildScan')){
    buildScan {
        termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service';
        termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'
    }
}
```

After executing, the result is as follow:

[image]

For the execution process, kindly refer to the [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRnjMqb47sI)

Why is it prompting "Class not found" error when I am actually executing from the said class ?

Comment: Probably test directory is in the wrong place, if not try to invalidate and restart Android Studio

Comment: @AntonisRadz Actually, what is the pourpose of the test directory, or how does one goes around to set it ? To where should it point to ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had these kind of issues a lot. For me, the simplest way to fix it was to create tests by opening the class that needs testing and pressing Ctr+Shift+t(Windows) or Cmd+Shift+t(Mac). After that I press the "Create new test" option. This creates the test file where Android Studio wants it and everything is fine.

Comment: Thqnks for the tip. However, I do not have a specific class  to test on. My test is calling directly to the AVD, and then simulate the tapping on the AVD by using AndroidDriver keyword(eg findElement etc.)